# OpenCV net.forward() throws "cv2.error: bad allocation" while while running YOLO vehicle detection

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

`cv2.error: bad allocation`

So I am following the tutorial on **https://www.folio3.ai/blog/car-detection-using-opencv-and-python-within-5-minutes/** in python environment.

But when the run the code it comes out with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 56, in <module>
    layerOutputs = net.forward(outputNames)
cv2.error: bad allocation
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be an indication that you need more RAM on your machine.

I got the same error when running deep learning model for up-scaling images.

More information here:
https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1334